# A clarification of Ramanujan's theorem.

Tags: modular-forms

I would like to know if my interpretation is right. Who can give me comfort?

In Notebook IV, Berndt reports Entry 11 (p. 328)
  [image]
and the proof that from, it's purely algebraic. However, I am sure that this theorem is nothing but a modular ninth-degree equation.
The reading key is as follows:

$x=\phi(q)$

$y=\phi(q^{9})$

$z=\phi^{4}(q^{3})$

and the theorem becomes:

"If $ \phi (q) = \phi (q ^ {9}) + \big(\frac{\phi ^ {4} (q ^ {3})} {\phi (q ^ {9})}-\phi ^{3}(q ^ {9})\big) ^ {1/3} $

Then

$3 \phi (q ^ {9}) = \phi (q) + \big (\frac{9 \phi^ {4} (q ^ {3})} {\phi (q)}-\phi^{3} (q ^ {3})\big) ^ {1/3} $ ".

From the third degree modular equation:

$\big(\frac{\phi(q)} {\phi(q^{3})})^{4}=1+2\sqrt{2} \frac{G_{n}^{3}} { G_{9n}^{9}}$

$=\frac{9} {1+2\sqrt{2} \frac{G_{9n}^{3}} { G_{n}^{9}}}$

Substituting the due variables you get the ninth degree modular equation:

$\frac{\phi(q)} {\phi(q^{9})}=1+\sqrt{2} \frac{G_{9n}} { G_{81n}^{3}}$

$3 \frac{\phi(q^{9})} {\phi(q)}=1+\sqrt{2} \frac{G_{9n}} { G_{n}^{3}}$.

$G_{n}, G_{9n}   ,and,  G_{81n}$ are Ramanujan's invariants.

$\phi(q)=1+2\big(q + q^{4} + q^{9} + q^{16}+...+q^{n^{2}})$.

Comment: Probably better to ask for "help" rather than "comfort." Languages change, the word comfort is commonly used when discussing help for a person who is ill, or when trying to help a person who is upset and weeping. Of course, it is possible that not knowing about Ramanujan's theorem has brought you to tears.

Comment: You are almost right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. The first degree 3 modular equation can be written as

$$ \phi(q)^4/\phi(q^3)^4 = 1 + 8\, q\, \chi(q)^3/\chi(q^3)^9.  \tag{1}$$

The dual equation can be written as

$$ 9\, \phi(q^3)^4/\phi(q)^4 = 1 + 8\, \chi(q^3)^3/\chi(q)^9.  \tag{2}$$

The first degree 9 modular equation can be written as

$$ \phi(q)/\phi(q^9) = 1 + 2\, q\, \chi(q^3)/\chi(q^9)^3.        \tag{3}$$

The second degree 9 modular equation can be written as

$$ 3\, \phi(q^9)/\phi(q) = 1 + 2\, \chi(q^3)/\chi(q)^3.           \tag{4}$$

where $\,\chi(q) = (-q,q^2)_{\infty}\,$ is one of Ramanujan's functions.

The two equations in Entry 11 **are** algebraically equivalent to

$$  \phi(q^3)^4 = \phi(q)^3\phi(q^9) - 3\,\phi(q)^2\phi(q^9)^2 + 3\,\phi(q)\phi(q^9)^3.    \tag{5}$$

and also to Berndt, Notebooks, Part III, p. 218, Equation (24.29).

The resultant of factoring equations $(2)$ and $(4)$, taking the numerators, and eliminating $\,\chi(q)\,$ is the cube of equation $(5)$ muliplied by the cube of $\,72\,(\chi(q^3)\,\phi(q))^3.\,$ This is the algebraic connection.

Comment: Thank you very much!